# custom vertex color with threejs LineSegments()

Tags: opengl-es, three.js, glsl, glsles

I am struggling with threejs to use a shaderMaterial on a THREE.LineSegments 
my goal is to have per vertex color, on a bunch of line segments:

I have a vertex and a fragment shader :

```
        <script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexshader">

            varying vec3 vColor;
            attribute vec3 customColor;             

            void main() {
                vColor = customColor;
            }

        </script>

        <script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentshader">

            varying vec3 vColor;

            void main() {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.0 );
            }

        </script>
```

then in the threejs scene , I create all the relevant stuff for the shader, and apply it to the object:

```
        var customColors = new Float32Array(_count*2*3); // 2 vertex by segment *length(RGB)
        for (var i = 0; i < customColors.length/3; i++) {
            var ratio  =  i / (customColors.length/3.0);
            customColors[(i*3)] = ratio;
            customColors[(i*3)+1] = ratio;
            customColors[(i*3)+2] = ratio;
        };

        geo.addAttribute('customColor' , new THREE.BufferAttribute(customColors,3));


        var drawCount = _count * 2;
        geo.setDrawRange( 0, drawCount );


        var uniforms = {
            opacity : 0.5

        };


        var customMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
            uniforms : uniforms,
            vertexShader : document.getElementById( 'vertexshader' ).textContent,
            fragmentShader : document.getElementById( 'fragmentshader' ).textContent,
            }
        );
        var lines = new THREE.LineSegments(geo, customMaterial);
```

I can't find where the problem is. 
The line segments don't appear at all,not even in black. 
All I have managed to do is to 'hard code' the color in the fragment shader ( which defeats the purpose evidently).

No error message whatsoever in the console.

please help, what am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling again , I finally can see some line segments with a custom vertex color. 
It looks I needed to give a value to the gl_Position variable ( I thought it would automatic, since I don't wan't to change vertex position).

I added this line into main() of the vertexShader:

```
gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
```